# How to count uploaded files in PHP?

Tags: php, loops, uploading

My newest problem is counting uploaded files. I already done this with `count($_FILES)`, but here is where problem is showing to me.
It shows only 3 files, and this is really strange, because I thought it works perfectly.
But to the point. Here's the code in PHP, and code with uploading files in HTML. When you look at the count function, you can see that I mentioned also name of the file. In my case it doesn't matter, because even if I type only `count($_FILES)` it doesn't work. I also tried with `var_dump($_FILES);` but it is showing only 1 file, instead of more.

```
$i = 0;
$target = "gallery/";
for($i=0; $i<=count($_FILES['ufile']); $i++) {
        if(($_FILES['ufile']['type'][$i]== 'image/jpeg')
        ||($_FILES['ufile']['type'][$i]== 'image/gif')
        ||($_FILES['ufile']['type'][$i]== 'image/png')
        &&($_FILES['ufile']['size'][$i]<5242880)
        &&($_FILES['ufile']['error'][$i] == 0)) {
                $image = $_FILES['ufile']["name"][$i];
                $temp = explode(".", $_FILES['ufile']["name"][$i]);
                $gallery_img = $i . '_' .round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp) ; //gallery is ready
                $final_gallery[$i] = $gallery_img;
                $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][$i];
                move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $target . $gallery_img);
    }
}
```

And HTML:

```
IMAGES TO GALLERY:<input name="ufile[]" type="file" id="ufile[]" multiple><br><br>
```

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES);` for enlightenment.

Comment: Now it shows only one file uploaded.

Comment: Add the output from the `var_dump()` to your question please

Comment: _“Now it shows only one file uploaded”_ - no, it doesn’t. You just have not managed to understand the actual data structure you get in this case yet.

Comment: Please just paste the output from your `var_dump($_FILES)` into your question, after attempting to upload ___more than one file___ I am sure this can be sorted out easily if we can see that

Comment: Quite simply you should be counting `$_FILES['ufile']['name']` or any of the `name,tmp_name,error,size,type` parameters to find out how many files are being uploaded

Comment: Just count($_FILES) and var_dump($_FILES) doesn't work. It shows less files than I uploaded.

Comment: Last time before I go else where!!!! ___Please___ paste the output from your `var_dump($_FILE)` ___into you question so we can see it___

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count($_FILES)` will show 1 in this case becuase you have only on input of `type = file`. If you were to add another input file type like the following then it will show 2.

```
//count($_FILES) will be 2 in this case.
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="ufile[]" type="file" id="ufile[]" multiple><br><br>
    <input name="extrafile" type="file" id="udfile[]" multiple><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload">
</form>
```

Now each file input when posted has 5 elements, which are `name`, `type`, `tmp_name`, `error` and `size`. So if you do `count($_FILES['ufile'])`, it will show always show 5.

**So the correct answer to count the number of files chosen for upload  in this case is** `count($_FILES['ufile']['name'])`

```
?>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="ufile[]" type="file" id="ufile[]" multiple><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload">
</form>
```

Comment: Okay, sorry for my previous comment, it is working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should try with this

```
for ($i=0; $i <= count($_FILES['ufile']['name']); $i++)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this
`count($_FILES['ufile']['name'])`

Comment: It also doesn't work. Commonly because file with the same name is only one.

Comment: @CvbgeXhapl Are you saying that you are trying to upload more than one file but they all have the same name?

Comment: No, I say why count($_FILES['ufile']['name']) doesn't work. the ['name'] attribute is giving name, and only one file has the same filename obviously. That's why it will show only one file.

Answer (score -1):

buddy! this should work for you

```
for($i=0; $i<=count($_FILES); $i++) {
```

Comment: I said that I already tried with count($_FILES). But thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: buddy! have you checked the output of var_dump($_FILES);  Is there anything in it ... are you using enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute with form tag

Comment: Yes, I have that attribute too.